# Use radial gradient as an extention for UIView

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cagradientlayer

My goal is to make radial gradient extension for UIView. Here is my code:

```
extension UIView {
    func drawRadialGradient() {
        let colors = Colors.gradientColors as CFArray
        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: colors, locations: nil)
        guard let gradientValue = gradient  else{ return }
        let endRadius: CGFloat? = max(frame.width, frame.height) / 2
        guard let endRadiusValue = endRadius else{ return }
        let bottomcenterCoordinates = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height)
        let getCurrentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        guard let currentContext = getCurrentContext else{ return }
        currentContext.drawRadialGradient(gradientValue, startCenter: bottomcenterCoordinates, startRadius: 0.0, endCenter: bottomcenterCoordinates, endRadius: endRadiusValue, options: CGGradientDrawingOptions.drawsAfterEndLocation)
        let radialGradientLayer = CALayer(layer: currentContext)
        radialGradientLayer.frame = bounds
        radialGradientLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.insertSublayer(radialGradientLayer, at: 1)
    }
}
```

When I call this function in viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear() the compiler contains no mistakes and no warnings, the function just does not work out. i call it as following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.drawRadialGradient()
}
```

For example, I have created an extension function for drawing a Linear Gradient on the UIView and it works, I call it the same way as radial gradient function:

```
func drawLinearGradient() {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.frame
    gradientLayer.colors = Colors.gradientColors
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.95)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.05)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

For colors I have created a structure:

```
struct Colors {
    static let firstColor = colorPicker(red: 70, green: 183, blue: 0)
    static let secondColor = colorPicker(red: 0, green: 170, blue: 116)
    static let thirdColor = colorPicker(red: 20, green: 0, blue: 204)
    static let gradientColors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor, thirdColor.cgColor]
    static func colorPicker(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        let color = UIColor(red: red / 255, green: green / 255, blue: blue / 255, alpha: 1.0)
        return color
    }
}
```

Please, give me a piece of advice on how to realize it as an extension.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for people to be able to help you, you should really give some more information. "it doesn't work" could mean anything. So explain where it goes wrong. What part does work and what doesn't? When you step through the code, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do, for example.

Comment: @fishinear, I have updated the code. Thank you for your kind advise. The compiler does not give any warnings at all and there are no messages in console also. The view, in which I call this function loads as usual with white background.

Comment: @Leo Dabus, thank you for a code style review!

Answer (score 0):

One main thing I can see in your code, is that you try to do the drawing in `viewDidLoad`. Don't do that, on top of other problems, the frame size is not properly set yet at that moment. If you want the `UIView` to do the drawing, then derive a class from `UIView`, and do the drawing in the `draw` method of that class.

If you want the `radialGradientLayer` `CALayer` that you created to do the drawing (it currently is just empty), then derive a subclass from `CALayer`, and implement its `drawInContext` method.